# If $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a convergent sequence with limit $a$, show that $(a_{\phi(n)})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ also converges with limit $a$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, permutations

Let $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a convergent sequence of real numbers with limit $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and let $\phi : \mathbb{N} \longrightarrow \mathbb{ N}$ an injective mapping. Show that the sequence $(a_{\phi(n)})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ also converges with limit $a$.

So I know that $(a_{\phi(n)})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is just a permutation and subsequence of $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$. I also know that any subsequence of a converging sequence also converges, I just don't know how to get to the point to proof that the permutation and its original would have the same limit. I've seen some similar questions on here, but none really answered it in respect to the permutation. Can anyone explain it with this specific subsequence?

Comment: Think about how many limit point(s) does a convergent sequence has?

Comment: Well, just one..

Comment: I believe you mean $(a_{\varphi(n)})$ is a *permutation of a subsequence of* $(a_n)$. Remember that convergence is all about what happens for $n \ge N$, for some $N$. Can you show that $\phi$ injective implies that for any $N$, there exists $N'$ s.t. $\forall n \ge N'$, $\phi(n) \ge N$? Can you see how to get to the result if this is true? (This is essentially the same as what Damian is saying, but more direct.)

Answer (score 1):

You can show that an equivalent definition of convergence that is agnostic to the ordering of $a_n$ is that $a_n \rightarrow a$ if and only if $\{n : |a_n - a| > \epsilon\}$ is finite for every $\epsilon > 0$.

But now, since $\phi$ is injective, we must have that
$$
\#\{\phi(n) : |a_{\phi(n)} - a| > \epsilon\}
\leq \#\{n : |a_n - a| > \epsilon\}
< \infty.
$$

Comment: Ah ok, thanks. Which part of that implies, that they both have the same limit?

Comment: The $a$ here is not generic, but a specific value. That is, $a_n \to a$ implies $\{n : |a_n - a| > \epsilon\}$ is finite, implies $\{\phi(n) : |a_{\phi(n)} - a| > \epsilon\}$ is finite, implies $a_{\phi(n)} \to a$. This doesn't hold for any number other than $a$.